# How can I interate through hours/dates and display data associated with each date in R using something like a gif?

Tags: r, plot, time, ggplot2, gif

I want to be able to step through my data, generating a plot for each day or perhaps week, and then display these plots in order.

I have data with dates and times associated with it in a dataframe. I first subset, and summarize this data and later create plots for each month, like so:

I think its less important but I use this code to generate summary data:

```
ridge_ls_hobo <-ridge_ls_hobo %>% group_by(canopy_understory, month, hour = cut(time, seq(0, 2400, 100), include.lowest = TRUE)) %>% summarise(temp_mean = mean(temp), temp_sd = sd(temp), light_mean =mean(intensity), light_sd = sd(intensity))
  edge_ls_hobo <-edge_ls_hobo %>% group_by(canopy_understory, month,season = ifelse(lubridate::month(date) < 5, 'dry', 'wet'), hour = cut(time, seq(0, 2400, 100), include.lowest = TRUE)) %>% summarise(temp_mean = mean(temp), temp_sd = sd(temp), light_mean =mean(intensity), light_sd = sd(intensity))
  valley_ls_hobo <-valley_ls_hobo %>% group_by(canopy_understory, month,season = ifelse(lubridate::month(date) < 5, 'dry', 'wet'), hour = cut(time, seq(0, 2400, 100), include.lowest = TRUE)) %>% summarise(temp_mean = mean(temp), temp_sd = sd(temp), light_mean =mean(intensity), light_sd = sd(intensity))
```

I later further subset it and generate plots with this code:

```
ggplot(data=na.omit(valley_sub_c_jan),aes(x = hour,y=temp_mean))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=temp_mean-temp_sd,ymax=temp_mean+temp_sd),colour="black")+
  geom_line(aes(y=temp_mean),colour="black",size=1)+
  geom_line(data = edge_sub_c_jan,aes(x=hour,y=temp_mean),colour="blue")+
  geom_errorbar(data=edge_sub_c_jan,aes(ymin=temp_mean-temp_sd,ymax=temp_mean+temp_sd),colour="blue")+
  geom_line(data = ridge_sub_c_jan,aes(x=hour,y=temp_mean),colour="red")+
  geom_errorbar(data=ridge_sub_c_jan,aes(ymin=temp_mean-temp_sd,ymax=temp_mean+temp_sd),colour="red")+
  theme_classic()+
  labs(x="Time",y="Temperature in canopy January")
```

This gives me an image something like this: 
[image of temperature over time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRwXa.png)

I could theoretically subset each hour period, save the image and put something together like this (which is what I did for the months time period). However, this seems as though it would be too incredibly time consuming and cumbersome for each hour for a dataset this large. I want to be able to generate plots and display them together (using a gif perhaps?). Can I accomplish this using R? Or at very least, can I iterate through the hours and generate/save the plots using R?

Here are example dputs of the three things I want to plot before summary data has been generated-

valley:

```
structure(list(canopy_understory = c("c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c"), trap_no = c(13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L), `#` = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 
45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 50L, 51L), date = structure(c(16809, 16809, 
16809, 16809, 16809, 16809, 16809, 16809, 16809, 16809, 16809, 
16809, 16810, 16810, 16810, 16810, 16810, 16810, 16810, 16810, 
16810, 16810, 16810, 16810, 16810, 16810, 16810, 16810, 16810, 
16810, 16810, 16810, 16810, 16810, 16810, 16810, 16811, 16811, 
16811, 16811, 16811, 16811, 16811, 16811, 16811, 16811, 16811, 
16811, 16811, 16811), class = "Date"), time = c(1200, 1300, 1400, 
1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900, 2000, 2100, 2200, 2300, 0, 100, 
200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 
1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900, 2000, 2100, 2200, 2300, 0, 
100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1300, 
1400), temp = c(39.502, 41.225, 31.064, 27.862, 26.683, 26.292, 
25.319, 24.738, 24.062, 24.158, 24.158, 23.869, 23.773, 23.677, 
23.581, 23.292, 23.196, 23.004, 22.908, 23.292, 25.125, 26.585, 
27.764, 29.352, 49.09, 43.359, 28.853, 28.555, 27.272, 26.39, 
25.319, 24.158, 24.062, 23.484, 23.1, 22.908, 22.525, 22.142, 
21.664, 21.282, 20.996, 20.615, 20.329, 20.424, 22.238, 25.513, 
27.961, 33.118, 46.722, 31.983), intensity = c(198, 165, 14, 
4, 1, 893.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 75.3, 1, 6, 
13, 16, 6, 187, 170, 5, 5, 1, 366, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 107.6, 1, 3, 44, 10, 46, 10, 38), coupler_attached = c("401.3", 
"334.4", "466.8", "133.4", "108.7", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "119.5", "544.5", "089.0", "533.4", 
"544.5", "379.0", "845.6", "166.7", "511.1", "463.9", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "463.9", "788.9", 
"089.2", "333.4", "844.8", "677.8", "578.0"), host_connected = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)), .Names = c("canopy_understory", 
"trap_no", "#", "date", "time", "temp", "intensity", "coupler_attached", 
"host_connected"), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

edge:

```
structure(list(canopy_understory = c("c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c"), trap_no = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), `#` = 1:50, 
    date = structure(c(16660, 16660, 16660, 16661, 16661, 16661, 
    16661, 16661, 16661, 16661, 16661, 16661, 16661, 16661, 16661, 
    16662, 16662, 16662, 16662, 16662, 16662, 16662, 16662, 16662, 
    16662, 16662, 16662, 16663, 16663, 16663, 16663, 16663, 16663, 
    16663, 16663, 16663, 16663, 16663, 16663, 16664, 16664, 16664, 
    16664, 16664, 16664, 16664, 16664, 16664, 16664, 16664), class = "Date"), 
    time = c(1800, 2000, 2200, 0, 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000, 1200, 
    1400, 1600, 1800, 2000, 2200, 0, 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000, 
    1200, 1400, 1600, 1800, 2000, 2200, 0, 200, 400, 600, 800, 
    1000, 1200, 1400, 1600, 1800, 2000, 2200, 0, 200, 400, 600, 
    800, 1000, 1200, 1400, 1600, 1800, 2000), temp = c(26.488, 
    24.641, 24.351, 24.448, 23.677, 23.004, 23.388, 25.708, 26.488, 
    34.479, 28.555, 25.708, 24.351, 23.966, 23.677, 23.388, 23.388, 
    23.484, 23.677, 38.046, 32.086, 33.953, 27.075, 29.053, 24.931, 
    24.255, 24.158, 24.062, 24.158, 24.351, 24.448, 25.513, 25.61, 
    27.075, 29.953, 25.125, 24.255, 23.773, 22.908, 23.004, 22.717, 
    22.525, 22.812, 27.37, 26.097, 34.796, 29.053, 28.953, 25.61, 
    24.641), intensity = c(312.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 6, 18, 44, 
    19, 4, 10.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 121, 35, 34, 15, 13, 32.3, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 452.1, 11, 6, 23, 34, 3, 32.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 22, 31, 60, 21, 13, 53.8, 0), coupler_attached = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "356.3", "544.5", "600.1", "089.2", "977.9", 
    "477.8", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "927.8", "245.2", "822.5", 
    "444.7", "844.5", "777.9", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "022.3", 
    "544.5", "422.4", "444.7", "961.1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    "894.5", "044.6", "689.1", "622.6", "355.7", "777.9", NA, 
    NA), host_connected = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)), .Names = c("canopy_understory", 
"trap_no", "#", "date", "time", "temp", "intensity", "coupler_attached", 
"host_connected"), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Ridge:

```
structure(list(canopy_understory = c("c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c"), trap_no = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L), `#` = 1:50, date = structure(c(16809, 
16809, 16809, 16809, 16809, 16809, 16809, 16809, 16809, 16809, 
16810, 16810, 16810, 16810, 16810, 16810, 16810, 16810, 16810, 
16810, 16810, 16810, 16810, 16810, 16810, 16810, 16810, 16810, 
16810, 16810, 16810, 16810, 16810, 16810, 16811, 16811, 16811, 
16811, 16811, 16811, 16811, 16811, 16811, 16811, 16811, 16811, 
16811, 16811, 16811, 16811), class = "Date"), time = c(1400, 
1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900, 2000, 2100, 2200, 2300, 0, 100, 
200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 
1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900, 2000, 2100, 2200, 2300, 0, 
100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 
1300, 1400, 1500), temp = c(35.542, 28.953, 27.468, 26.977, 25.708, 
24.931, 24.062, 24.062, 24.158, 23.773, 23.677, 23.677, 23.581, 
23.196, 23.004, 22.717, 22.717, 23.292, 26.292, 27.764, 29.252, 
30.356, 33.639, 36.187, 32.394, 30.154, 28.159, 26.977, 25.708, 
24.255, 23.966, 23.196, 23.196, 23.004, 22.429, 22.046, 21.378, 
21.091, 20.615, 20.234, 20.043, 20.805, 25.513, 30.356, 31.064, 
31.983, 33.639, 38.268, 42.52, 31.064), intensity = c(41, 4, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 86.1, 3, 13, 13, 6, 
6, 17, 154, 126, 10, 2, 538.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 172.2, 4, 12, 79, 14, 14, 44, 63, 170, 8), coupler_attached = c("333.6", 
"994.5", "184.0", "033.3", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "100.0", "089.0", "777.9", "544.5", "544.5", 
"222.3", "312.1", "756.4", "677.8", "238.9", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "133.4", "400.1", "911.6", 
"466.8", "466.8", "089.2", "378.2", "845.6", "266.7"), host_connected = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)), .Names = c("canopy_understory", 
"trap_no", "#", "date", "time", "temp", "intensity", "coupler_attached", 
"host_connected"), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Maybe something like `gganimate` from package *gganimate*?

Comment: @aosmith thanks! I'll check it out